# Laravel 5.4 foreign key relation show null in table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to save the Client and device foreign keys in my inquiry table but somehow it keeps returning null(my Migration for that is nullable). I get no Errors if I return $Client or $device it Returns a correct id.

This is how the Controller Looks like:

```
# foreign key in this table rreturns null InquiryController
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $client = Client::find($request->input('client_id'));
    $device = Device::find($request->input('device_id'));
    $stream = new Stream;
    $stream->stream_name = $request->input('stream_name');
    $stream->save();

    $inquiry = new Inquiry;
    $inquiry->fill($data);
    $inquiry->client()->associate($client);
    $inquiry->device()->associate($device);
    $inquiry->stream()->associate($stream);
    $inquiry->save();
}
```

And this is my Inquiry Model

```
class Inquiry extends Model
{
    protected $table    = 'inquiries';
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'client_id', 'device_id', 'stream_id'];

    # relations
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }
    public function device()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Device::class);
    }
    public function stream()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Stream::class);
    }
}
```

this is the relation function for the Client and device model:

```
public function inquiry()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Inquiry::class);
}
```

The Migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('inquiries', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('client_id')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedInteger('device_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('device_id')->references('id')->on('devices')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('inquiries');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have your foreign keys defined in the migration for the `inquiry` table.

For example:

```
$table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('client_id')
  ->references('id')->on('clients')
  ->onDelete('cascade');
```

**Update:**

Try saving the model before adding the relationships.  Swap it around to:

```
$inquiry = new Inquiry;
$inquiry->fill($data);
$inquiry->save();
$inquiry->client()->associate($client);
$inquiry->device()->associate($device);
$inquiry->stream()->associate($stream);
```

Comment: Try saving the model before adding in the relationships

Comment: Also, your migration seems to be missing the column for `stream_id` and setting it up as a foreign key.